# How to configure dynamic WEP in command line

Tags: certificates

My ISP force to use certificates through IEEE 802.1x
Standard to log into their (NOT!-wireless) network.

There's a Client Certificate `MyName.p12` and a Server Certificate `hotzoneCA.der`. I must give my MAC address too.

There's no NetworkManager for the wired that I know, but I want to log in with my Raspberry and I don't know how to import the certificates the right way.

edit: My ISP don't want to support Linux, I should google "xsupplicant" and "eap-tls" and try to get it running. But I'm not sure if the hint is useful.

Comment: Can you precise your question, be more specific and maybe paste a link to your ISP? Is it http://hotzone.de? Are you talking about a VPN login? http://www.hotzone.de/en/faq

Comment: A Link to my ISP: http://hotzone.de/
I must use it, because I live in a student dormitory and this is the only ISP here.

I don't know how to be more specific. In Windows I "install" the Certificates and then I log in over ethernet. When I use Linux I can only use Certificates, when I use a wireless connection.

Comment: It's not a VPN, it's a kind of authentication. Look here, when I use wireless ethernet, I can put the certificates in like this: http://hotzone.de/uploads/Giqtv67H-rx_dzRy9WvRxQ/xuNSDbXWdc7LqEzCeBpG4A/D_WLAN_Linux.pdf . But in our dormitory we can just use ethernet and in Linux I can't put the certificates "on the system". 

PS: Sorry, can't edit the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Ubuntu install `wpa_supplicant`:

   `sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant`
2. Edit the wpa_supplicant configuration file (e.g. /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf), ant put the following:

   ```
   network={
      ssid="YOUR-SSID"
      scan_ssid=1
      key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
      pairwise=CCMP TKIP
      group=CCMP TKIP
      eap=TLS
      identity="XXXXX@yourdomain.com"
      ca_cert="/etc/certs/cacert.pem"
      client_cert="/etc/certs/cert.pem"
      private_key="/etc/certs/key.pem"
      private_key_passwd="YOUR-PASSWORD"
   }
   ```

   `"YOUR-PASSWORD"` is the password provided by your administrator when your received your .p12 certificate. `"YOUR-SSID"` is the (B/E)SSID of the wireless access network
3. Start wpa_supplicant

   `wpa_supplicant -B -i IFACE -Dwext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

   Where `IFACE` is the name of your wireless interface.
4. Check that you are associated

   ```
   iwconfig IFACE
   ```

   To get an IP address use

   ```
   dhclient IFACE
   ```

Comment: Like I said, before you " improved" my question: I can configure it in a wireless connection, but I have a wired (normal ethernet). So i can't use the certificates at (normal) ethernet.

I don't know if the hint of my ISP was useful, sometimes when I'm talking to them I think they don't know what they do.

Comment: I didn't change your question, just make the title more comprehensible. Feel free to specify your question, so that the returned answers are helpful to you. - How else can I know what *you* want to do ...?

Comment: I used your advice and know why it didn't worked... I used the "tunneled TLS", but when I looked at your help here I try the normal "TLS" and then it worked perfect. Thank you!